# How to grep for a specific pattern and print everything above and below that pattern until you reach an indicator (LINUX)?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

So I am trying to grep for a specific pattern and then print everything above and below that pattern up to a specific indicator. I don't know if this is possible with grep or if I should you some other tool like awk, sed, or generate some shell script. So if I have the following:

```
---------------
     .....
process: failed
     ......
----------------
```

and

```
----------------
     .....
process: frozen
     .....
----------------
```

I want to grep for 'process: frozen' and want everything between the dashed lines when 'process: frozen' is found. However the number of lines between the dashed lines may vary for different 'process: frozen' messages, so I can't count the number of lines above or below and use the -A and -B option of grep. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use GNU `awk` and set the record separator to a string which contains 16 hypens:

```
awk '/process: (failed|frozen)/' RS='-{16}' input.file
```

Comment: Doesn't work; `^` and `$` aren't taken to mean beginning and end of line but of input in this context. Also, regex `RS` is gawk-specific.

Comment: It looked like it should work at first glance, and the idea isn't bad in general. I might use `RS='\n-+\n'`, I think, to be on the safe side. Although this may lead to a first and last delimiter line making it into the output, which would have to be `sub`ed out.

Comment: I does work using `RS='-{16}'`. I like this solution most. The problem with `\n-+\n` is that on the first line the hyphens might not being prefixed by a `\n` and the last line might not being suffixed by a `\n`, but however this depends on the input format (it is not 100% clear atm).

Comment: Depends on what can appear between the delimiter lines, I suppose. Anyway, it shows the general principle and is straightforward to amend in case of difficulties. Good enough for me.

Comment: @pdm You are welcome, but note that it will work with `GNU awk` only! Thanks for your help @Wintermute.

Comment: Yeah the messages that are being generated wont have a '-' between the delimiter lines. So it should be good for all scenarios. But I think I will play it safe and go with RS='-{16}'

Comment: Is there a way to still print out the hyphens?

Comment: You can use the `ORS` (*output record separator*) variable. Like this: `awk '/process: (failed|frozen)/' RS='-{16}' ORS='-----------------' input.file`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply delete the line containing the `process: frozen` or `process: failed` message in `sed`.

```
sed "/process: frozen/d"
```