# grep for Error and print all the lines containing 2 strings above and below Error

Tags: bash, sed

```
saaa vcahJJ HKak vk     
Import xxx xXXXXX xxxx
aaaa aaaa  aaaa ffffff
hhhhhh hhhhhh hhh hhh  hhhhhh
Error reading readStatus api
aaa hhhh aaa aaaaa
gggggggg ggggg xxxxxxxxxx
uuuu hhhhhhhh fffffffff
query run ends
qidIdih II v iQE Iqe
```

I want to find the `'Error'` string in the file containing above logs and then print all the info available between 2 strings `'Import'` and `'ends'`.
How can I do this using `grep/sed`
Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268476/how-to-grep-for-a-specific-pattern-and-print-everything-above-and-below-that-pat) 
but didn't get much. 
Note:  I dont know how many lines will be before and after. It may vary from above sample I have provided

Comment: Can you post what did you try ?

Comment: awk '/^Error/' ORS='ends' file.txt   --- but without success

Comment: @tripleee , I am not sure it"s a duplicate. between two marker yes, but there is one more condition here.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; removed the duplicate flag albeit hesitantly. Do you really think this needs to exist as a separate question?

Comment: @tripleee. I don't know exactly. I have'nt read all the aswer in the link but I'm not sure the OP can find a solution for him in the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Grep's `-A 1` option will give you one line after; `-B 1` will give you one line before; and `-C 1` combines both to give you one line both before and after.

```
grep -C 1 "Error" <logfile>
```

As per your requirement, You can use-

```
sed -n '/Import/,/ends/p' filename
```

Comment: sorry for not being clear in my query, I dont know how many lines will be before and after. It may vary from above sample I have provided

Comment: is there any way to check specifically for 'Import' and 'ends' and grep the contents between these 2

Comment: Yes.. Edited the answer. Please check

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="ends\n"} /Error/' file
```

`RS` is the input record separator which needs to be `ends`. `ORS`gets the same value for output purposes. Also, your example had `/^Error/` but `Error` does not start the record (`^`).

Comment: how to do if i have some more lines before 'Import' line

Comment: Please, update the sample data to reflect the real situation. Guessing game is not appreciated here as it's a waste of everyones' time.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
out=$( sed -n '/^Import/,/end$/p' file )
echo "$out" | grep Error >/dev/null && echo "$out"
```

This will capture the text between "Import" and "end" and print it only if the extracted text contains "Error".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed

```
sed '/^Import/!d;:A;N;/\nImport/{h;s/.*\n//;bA};/ends$/!bA;h;s/\nError//;tB;d;:B;x' infile
```

Explanation :

```
sed '
/^Import/!d                 # if a line start with Import
:A
N                           # get an other line
/\nImport/{h;s/.*\n//;bA}   # if the last line start with Import
                            # keep only this last line and return to A
/ends$/!bA                  # If the last line end with ends
h                           # keep all the lines in the hold space
s/\nError//                 # look for a line which start with Error
tB                          # if find jump to B
d                           # not find, delete all and return to the start
:B
x                           # restore all the lines and print
' infile
```