# grep multiple type error string and text in single log file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have asked similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47412728/grep-for-error-and-print-all-the-lines-containing-2-strings-above-and-below-erro), but this one I feel is more complicated than that so, asking in different post.

```
foo foo foo foo foo
Import blash blah blah
foo foo foo foo foo 
blah blah blah blah 
Error loading file
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
query run ends
foo foo foo foo
Import blash blah blah
foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo 
Exception occurred
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
query run ends
Import blash blah blah
foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo 
query run ends
```

In the pattern similar to above, I want to grep all the contents between all **Import** and **ends** if **Error** or **Exception** exist in between them.
And in that process I want to exclude those *Import & ends* combination which doesn't have any *Error or Exception* string.

### **Note:**

The lines between **Import & ends** strings are not constant, it may vary.

### Expected:

```
Import blash blah blah
foo foo foo foo foo 
blah blah blah blah 
Error loading file
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
query run ends
Import blash blah blah
foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo 
Exception occurred
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
query run ends
```

Comment: post the final expected result for your current input

Comment: updated in the query

Answer (score 0):

If your data does not contain any blank lines, you could do:

```
nl='
'; sed -n -e "/Import/,/ends/{/ends/s/\$/\\$nl/; p;}" input |
     awk /Exception\|Error/ RS=
```

This is just pre-processing the data to remove all lines that do not appear between `Import` and `ends`, and adds a blank line between records.  With the data in that format, the `awk` solution is trivial.  (I don't normally condone piping sed to awk, but it's not unusual to do that sort of thing when each step has a different record separator)

If your data does potentially have blank lines, you could pre and post process with something like:

```
nl='
'; sed -n -e '/^$/s/^/BLANK LINE/' -e "/Import/,/ends/{/ends/s/\$/\\$nl/; p;}" input |
     awk /Exception\|Error/ RS= | sed 's/^BLANK LINE$//'
```

Note, there are cleaner ways to insert a blank line. Also, there's is a certain fragility in pre/post processing like this; namely, you need to pick a sentinel (the string "BLANK LINE") as some string that does not appear in your input.

Answer (score 0):

The same sed as yesterday with one more condition.

```
sed '/^Import/!d;:A;N;/\nImport/{h;s/.*\n//;bA};/ends$/!bA;h;s/\nException//;tB;s/\nError//;tB;d;:B;x' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

using `awk` to print from "Import" to "ends" when this block contains "Error" or "Exception".

```
awk '/Import/,/ends/                 {s = s "\n" $0} 
     /ends/ && s ~ /Error|Exception/ {print s; s=""}' file
```

output for the example input.

```
Import blash blah blah
foo foo foo foo foo 
blah blah blah blah 
Error loading file
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
query run ends

Import blash blah blah
foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo 
Exception occurred
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
query run ends
```

Answer (score -1):

GNU **`awk`** solution (assuming `Import` keyword doesn't occur within intermediate text):

```
awk -v RS='Import' '$0~/\<(Error|Exception)/{ printf "%s%s",RS,$0 }' file
```

- `-v RS='Import'` - treat `Import` keyword as record separator

---

The output:

```
Import blash blah blah
foo foo foo foo foo 
blah blah blah blah 
Error loading file
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
query run ends
Import blash blah blah
foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo 
Exception occurred
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
query run ends
```

Comment: thanks @RomanPerekhrest , is it possible to put 'ends' keyword too as RS which will be helpful if logs pattern contain some other records between 'ends' and next 'Import'??

Comment: updated the the original post too with change in pattern

Comment: Note that using more than a single character for RS is a gnu awk extension and will not work in all implementations of awk.